# Fire Tabsselect for first Jquery UI Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a series of large methods tied to the 'tabsselect' event, but Jquery UI does not fire for the initial tab, and using the select method on the first tab does not fire the tabsselect event.

I have also tried manually triggering 'tabsselect' on the first tab, however:

```
$('#tabContainer').trigger('tabsselect');
```

does not fire the events,

```
$('#firstTab').trigger('tabsselect');
```

does not give the correct parameters to use in the methods (function (event, ui)).

Anyone got around this problem? I have to avoid calling an alternate tab, then calling back to the correct initial tab, since these methods do a large amount of processing to initialise the page and save tab view history.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
$('#tabs').trigger( "tabselect", {index:the_selected_tab_number});
```

You need to have the function attached to tabselect event for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than triggering the `tabsselect`, you should simply try triggering the `click` event for that tab.

So your code will look like this:

```
$('#firstTab').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Didn't work. Not sure why it would either, clicking on an already active tab would not trigger a selection.

Comment: According to the [jQuery UI Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Tabs#event-select): "This event is triggered when clicking a tab" so triggering a click event should trigger the tabsselect